# Modifying label and tick on color bar of Plots.jl plot

Tags: julia, scatter, plots.jl, julia-plots

I have a scatter plot generated using `Plots.jl` in Julia via `Plots.scatter(x, y, marker_z = z)`. This results in a scatter plot of `x` and `y`, where points are colored according to the corresponding values in `z`. There is a vertical color bar to the right of the scatter plot that indicates what colors correspond to what values of `z`.

I would like to modify the vertical color bar but was not able to find any details on how best to do this. The specific tasks I am interested in are:

1. I would like to add a label for the color bar.
2. I would like to modify the ticks on the color bar.

Answer (score 4):

Use `colorbar_ticks` and `colorbar_title`

```
using Plots
pyplot()
colorbar_ticks=(0:0.2:1.0, string.(round.(Int, (0:0.2:1.0) .* 100), "%"))
Plots.scatter(rand(10), rand(10), marker_z = rand(10), colorbar_ticks=colorbar_ticks,clim=(0,1), colorbar_title="My title")
```

[image]